# iAd alongside UIWebView (iPad)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, iad

I want to create an iPad app which will initially show a Table View and on click of any of the table rows show a detail view (a UIWebView)

Now on this detail view, I also want to show an iAd (may be at the bottom)

How do I do this? Any example app with source code for reference would be really helpful . Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by creating a custom UIViewController that operates as a UIWebViewDelegate & AdBannerViewDelegate. The view controller will load two subviews--a UIWebView and an AdBannerView.

A tap on your UITableViewCell pushes the custom view controller, which is responsible for loading appropriate content in the UIWebView & displaying the contents of the AdBannerView.

Comment: Thx a lot for that...Could u pls provide me any sample app with source code for the same...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a sample app with source code for doing this. You would build this like any other view controller to which you add subviews. Here's a nice tutorial from a great dev you can look at to undertand how to put some of the pieces together for your own app: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app